# Why do cosplay competitions require prerecorded dialogue?

Tags: conventions, cosplay

From [local](https://www.animeevolution.com/programming/contests/cosplay-contest/cosplay-skit-pre-registration/) [performances](http://www.a-kon.com/Explore/Cosplay/Cosplay-Contest-Rules) to bigger contests like [EuroCosplay](http://www.abunaicon.nl/programme/competitions/euro-cosplay-competition-eurocos/), many cosplay performances require you to prerecord your music and dialogue.

Usually it is part of the rules for participation. What is the reason for this requirement? Surely a 'live' dialogue would make the act seem more convincing - rather than cosplayers having to lip sync.

I understand mic's aren't great if you have giant lobster claws or something - but microphones can come pretty small now and could fit in a helmet. Even still, why restrict **all** cosplayers?

Why does this rule exist?

Comment: The costume can be heavy, moving around in it while talking might result in unclear voice due to heavy breathing. Another reason might be to prevent nervousness. Not all people can speaking in public like nothing.

Comment: Yeah but it shouldn't be forced because of nervousness. Instead, nervous people should have the choice to have prerecorded audio. Im not convinced that's the reason.

Comment: If the contest is in a big hall like what i've seen in Supernova Photos it might be so that way the participants don't have to scream out for everyone to hear them

Comment: I think it would allow them to keep schedules better because they'll know exactly how long each act will be.

Comment: also to enforce @AyaseEri comment, aside from going to work to make money to buy more stuff don't Otaku's normally stay inside and rarely go outside or even speak to huge audiences?

Comment: It might be enforced so that everyone has the same rules applied. Otherwise, those with great public speaking skill would have the advantage over those without.

Comment: AFAIK, you can have a mic for your performance if you ask for one, at least in some french conventions. After discussing with a friend which is fund of cosplay, she has already seen coplayers singing during their performances. It may depend on the association which is organizing the contest. What's more, the association often ask to the cosplayers to give them the sound track they will be playing **or a record of what they will sing or say** so they can determine whether or not its content is suitable for the audience of the contest.

Comment: Having worked with Pro AV people, I can say that trying to get technology to work last minute in a performance setting, it never goes well when you do it on the fly. #sunSpots

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that it is a primarily time-management strategy. From the Oyahocon Cosplay Competition rules (bold text mine):

> The music and/or prerecorded dialogue must be ready to go as soon as it is put the CD player (this means the participant must edit the music and/or prerecorded dialogue before the convention and put it on a CD). **Audio file must be exactly three (3) minutes or less. There are NO exceptions to the rule. If the audio file is longer than three (3) minutes, it will be stopped when time is reached (even if it cuts the performance).** Please have files recorded exactly as you wish them to be played.

From Anime Midwest competition rules:

> The pre-recorded music/dialogue submitted to the Masquerade staff must be 2 minutes and 30 seconds or less. **There will be no exceptions to the "2 Minute" rule, unless you request permission prior to the convention. Any entry over the 2:30 mark will be stopped at that point.**

From Anime-Expo Performance competition rules:

> **Adhere to the 2 minute time limit.**
>   MC and video introductions will not count towards the performance time.
>   Audio: Any sound necessary to express your performance (i.e. music, pre-recorded dialogue, sound effects).
>   Must be comparable to a PG rating– no profanity or offensive language. Bleeps or other forms of censoring are acceptable.
>   **Should not exceed 2 minutes.**
>   Must be MP3 format.
>   Must have minimum 192 bitrate.
>   Try to avoid audio quality defects (audible distortion, overdriven levels, low sample-rate/bitrate).